# Joining grouped tables

Tags: birt

I have two different scripted data sets that I am pulling data from and aggregating (on the same key). What I want to do is to display one one line the aggregated data from both sources. The data is coming from a scripted data source (POJOs).

A simplified example is given below in which an Order has many Components, with each component being for a different customer at a different quoted price. Then when each Order is filled in different lots (or Fills) at different prices. I want to be able to produce a summary of each Order with the total Ordered and Filled quantity, and the weighted average quoted price and filled price.

An Order Component table

```
Order ID, Customer Num, Qty, Quoted Px 
Ord01,Cust01,3,100
Ord01,Cust02,3,102 
Ord02,Cust01,5,200 
Ord02,Cust03,5,204
```

And then a Order Fullfillment table

```
OrderID,FillId,Qty,CostPx 
Ord01,F01,4,100 
Ord01,F02,2,106 
Ord02,F03,2,200
Ord02,F04,8,210'
```

I would like to display something like this:

```
Order ID, Order Qty, Fill Qty, Avg Order Px, Avg Fill Px
Ord01, 6, 6, 101, 102
Ord02, 10, 10, 202, 208
```

I've tried using subreports and that seems to be able to get me the results but in a terrible format. The subtable headers repeat so every order gets it's own headers.

Comment: What are your underlying data sources - relational databases, XML files, ...?

Comment: It's a scripted data source, coming from a Java server.

Comment: Yes, you said that in the original question - what are the **underlying** data sources?

Comment: @MarkBannister - you'll have to be a bit more specific than that I'm afraid. As I said before the data is being fetched from a Java component as a List of POJOs (different objects for each of the two datasets). I'm using a scripted dataset to extract the fields into the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by more or less following the following [guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rdahelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/subreport.13.11.html).

So I created a List linked to my first data source. I then added a group on Order ID so that I had one list row per Order. In the group header I added a 2x1 grid, I placed a table of the Order Components into one side of the grid and a table of Fills into the other. I had to add filters to both of these so that they only contained data for the correct OrderId. I then grouped the tables by OrderId, added my aggregation fields.

All that is left is to set the visibilty. So I set the visibility of the table details to false. In order to only show the table header once (instead of once per order) I added a Running Count aggregation to the List and set the visibiity to invisible when this aggregation was greater than 1.

Was actually quite easy in the end but took me ages to work out how to do it.

Comment: You should accept this answer, so the question does not come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a BIRT joined dataset between your two scripted datasets, based on a full outer join on the "order ID" column, and then use this joined dataset in your report. It should meet your needs.

Comment: A Full outer join as you describe would give me the cross product of OrderComponents and Fills for an Order ID. I.e. I'd get four rows for Order01 and the totals wouldnt add up properly.

Comment: mmmh you are right. Though i already managed something like this with a joined dataset, by checking values in the onFetch event: if the "key" orderId+customerId has not changed since the previous row, then set the two first fields to 0. Glad you could resolve your issue!